# Update ruby on rails version that time issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I update ruby version 2.3.0 to 2.4.0 and also update rails version 2.4.0 to 2.4.8, after the update version I faced issue on server log.
in my local development server log is not proper. like I start rails server and click on my web page that time log is not coming.

Comment: Needed more details

Comment: means which type of detail you want to need ?

Comment: How did you update Ruby and Rails version?? Run `bundle install and restart your server, this may help. If you get an error please post here if possible.

Comment: There's no Rails 2.4.8

Comment: /users/leber2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@agree_repo/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/users/leber2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@agree_repo/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting
@NirajKaushal